# how to optimize the mysql Query

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

how  to  increase  the  performance of  this mysql  query

```
SELECT ''                                           AS sharedid,
       hubber_posts.userID                          AS postowner,
       hubber_posts.*,
       ''                                           AS sharedby,
       hubber_posts.userID                          AS userID,
       hubber_posts.posted_date                     AS DATE,
       ''                                           AS sharebyusr,
       ''                                           AS sharebyusrimg,
       Concat_ws(' ', firstname, lastname)          AS fullname,
       username                                     AS postedBy,
       hubber_user.image,
       hubber_user.gender                           AS gender,
       (SELECT accounttype
        FROM   hubber_user_security us
        WHERE  hubber_user.ID = us.userID
               AND hubber_posts.userID = us.userID) AS accounttype,
       ''                                           AS sharebyusrtype
FROM   hubber_posts
       INNER JOIN hubber_user
               ON hubber_posts.userID = hubber_user.ID
WHERE  hubber_posts.status = 1
```

Comment: Please try to put some effort into formatting t he query.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Performance questions should include EXPLAIN ANALYZE and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. Slow is a relative term and we need a real value to compare. MySQL Also Please read [How-to-Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You do need to read this for advice asking a question we can answer. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to support a join where hubber_posts is the base table and the 2 other tables are joined using nested loops.

- No need to index hubber_posts for the join.
- hubber_user.ID should be a PK.
- hubber_user_security.userID should be indexed (and defined as a FK references hubber_user.ID).

As for the WHERE clause - only if you have relatively few rows where hubber_posts.status = 1 then you should add an index on hubber_posts.status

P.s.

since the join contain the condition -

```
ON hubber_posts.userID = hubber_user.ID
```

There is no need to compare both `hubber_posts.userID` and `hubber_user.ID` to `us.userID`

Answer (score 0):

Your example code has a correlated subquery. MySQL performs poorly with those, as of late 2016.

Try converting it to a JOINed table.

```
   SELECT all that stuff,
          us.accounttype
     FROM   hubber_posts
     JOIN hubber_user ON hubber_posts.userID = hubber_user.ID
     LEFT JOIN hubber_user_security us ON hubber_user.ID = us.userID
    WHERE  hubber_posts.status = 1
```

I used `LEFT JOIN`. Without the `LEFT`, any rows without a matching entry in that table will be suppressed from the result set.

Answer (score 0):

You query is essentially this:

```
SELECT . . .
       (SELECT accounttype
        FROM   hubber_user_security us
        WHERE  u.ID = us.userID AND
               p.userID = us.userID
       ) AS accounttype,
       . . .
FROM hubber_posts p INNER JOIN
     hubber_user u
     ON p.userID = u.ID
WHERE p.status = 1 ;
```

For this query, the optimal indexes are:

- `hubber_posts(status, userId)`
- `hubber_user(Id)`
- `hubber_user_security(userId)`

I would note that the subquery has an extra correlation condition that is not necessary -- the user ids are already equal.  And, you run the risk of getting an error if there are multiple account types.

You may intend:

```
   (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(accounttype)
    FROM   hubber_user_security us
    WHERE  u.ID = us.userID
   ) as accounttypes,
```